# mysql duplicate data error

Tags: php

I'm facing a weird problem with my PHPmyAdmin while inserting query!
it shows that the data are duplicate but it doesn't, here's the error message bellow:

Error
SQL query: Edit

```
INSERT INTO  `a5693029_mydb`.`student` (

`stuID` ,
`stuName` ,
`stuMajor`
)
VALUES (
'20120176106', NULL , NULL
)
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> `#`1062 - Duplicate entry '2147483647' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 2):

You need to change the definition of `StuId`. It cannot store numbers larger than 2147483647 (signed 32 bit limitation)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a field in your table that as hit its maximum value. Increase the fieldsize to be able to insert another row.

You have a ton of rows :)

Comment: To me it looks like a combined key, not an auto-increment issue. The 2012 looks like year and 01 may be January. The rest could be incremented though.